# find the first matching value when comparing two arrays javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop

I'm trying to find a match between the breeds array and the dogs array. How can I return the first match that is found. This is what i have that doesn't seem to work and I cant quite find the error. Thanks

```
var dogs = ["pug", "husky", "hound", "poodle"];

function findTheBreed(dogs) {
    var breeds = ["terrier", "mix", "lab", "hound"];
 for(let i = 0; i < dogs.length; i++) {
   for (let b = 0; b < breeds.length; b++) {
     if(dogs[i] === breeds[b]) {
       return breeds[b]
      } else {
       return "no match"
      }
    }
   }
 }
```

Comment: How do you determine which dog matches which breed? Is there a dog - breed mapping somewhere you forgot to declare? Or is it just quirky naming?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're returning false on the first non-match, whereas you should continue iterating.

move the `return "no match"` to after everything has been iterated through.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7o6g2dzv/)

You can alternatively also use the `indexOf` here:

```
function findTheBreed(dogs) {
    var breeds = ["terrier", "mix", "lab", "hound"];
    for(let i = 0; i < dogs.length; i++) {
      if(breeds.indexOf(dogs[i]) != -1){
      return dogs[i];
    }
  }   
  return "no match";
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7o6g2dzv/1/)

One other (in my opinion the best) route would be to use the [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter?v=control) functionality and retrieve the entire array of matches.

```
  var breeds = ["terrier", "mix", "lab", "hound", "snickerdoodle"];
    var filtered = breeds.filter(
    function (elem) {
      return dogs.indexOf(elem) != -1
    }
  );
  return filtered;
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7o6g2dzv/5/)

Answer (score 2):

It would be simpler to turn one array into a dictionary and do a direct lookup.

For example, if dog is turned into a dictionary

```
var dictionary = {};
for(var i=0;i<dogs.length;i++){
  dictionary[dogs[i]] = true;
}

for(var i=0;i<breeds.length;i++){
  if(dictionary[breeds[i]] === true) return true; //found match
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Or shorter:

```
var findtheBreed=dogs=>["terrier","mix","lab","hound"].find(breed=>dogs.find(dog=>dog===breed))||"no match";

alert(findtheBreed(["pug","husky","hound","poodle"]));
```

http://jsbin.com/mubatiyebo/edit?console

using *Array.prototype.find* , *Arrow functions* and the brilliant *OR* operator...

Comment: I'd suggest the shorter `breed => dogs.includes(breed)`

Answer (score 1):

To fix your implementation, move the `return "no match"` out of the loop body to the end of your `findTheBreed` function.

However, you can find the first match faster - in constant time - by leveraging constant time `Set.has` lookup:

```js
function match(dogs, breeds) {
  return dogs.find(Set.prototype.has, new Set(breeds));
}

let dogs = ["pug", "husky", "hound", "poodle"];
let breeds = ["terrier", "mix", "lab", "hound"];

console.log(match(dogs, breeds));
```

Also, I think you should consider renaming your arrays as there is currently no distinction between a `dog` and a `breed`. Also, you might consider declaring the `breeds` as a `Set` from the beginning on to avoid redundant conversion.

Comment: @Jonasw Would also work for your approach: `dogs.find(Array.prototype.includes, breeds)` or even shorter `dogs.find([].includes, breeds)` - however I feel that explicitly declaring an arrow function callback as you did is easier to grasp for learners / OP.

Answer (score 0):

You're returning out of the function too early.
If you want the same data structure, maybe try this:

```
var dogs = ["pug", "husky", "hound", "poodle"];
function findBreed(dogs) {
    var breeds = ["terrier", "mix", "lab", "hound"];
    for (let i = 0; i < dogs.length; i++){
        var dog = dogs[i];
        var successIdx = breeds.indexOf(dog)
        if (successIdx !== -1){
            return dog
        }

    }
    return "no match"
 }
```