# If the input I put blank, then it will count 0

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to put some amount, then it will show the calculation if all input will given any number, but I want, when I do not put anything in any one of that input, then the input will count "0" automatically..

```
<body>
    <input type='text' id='aaa'/>
    <input type='text' id='bbb'/>
    <input type='text' id='ccc'/>
    <input type='text' id='answer' name='ans' />
<form name ="testarea" Method="GET" Action="" id='form1'>
    <input type="button" onClick="Calculate();" value="calculate"/>
</form>
</body>
<script>


    function Calculate()
        {
        var aaa= document.getElementById('aaa').value;
        var bbb= document.getElementById('bbb').value;
        var ccc= document.getElementById('ccc').value; 
        var permin = parseFloat(aaa) * 82;
        var permin1 = parseFloat(bbb) * 40;
        var permin2 = parseFloat(ccc) * 10;
        var permin3=permin+permin1+permin2;
        document.getElementById('answer').value=permin3;
        document.form1.submit();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Why not do Calculate(aaa = 0), and force the parameter to have a default value?

Comment: `"SyntaxError: expected expression, got keyword 'var'"`

Comment: I recommend `getElementById(...).valueAsNumber`

Comment: I tried, but if left any input blank then, the ans comes NaN @le_m

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    var aaa= document.getElementById('aaa').value;
    var bbb= document.getElementById('bbb').value;
    var ccc= document.getElementById('ccc').value; 
    var permin = (parseFloat(aaa)||0) * 82;
    var permin1 = (parseFloat(bbb)||0) * 40;
    var permin2 = (parseFloat(ccc)||0) * 10;
    var permin3=permin+permin1+permin2;
    document.getElementById('answer').value=permin3;
```

You can use the OR operator to replace `NaN` with 0 if parseFloat returns `NaN`.

You could shorten the upper code to:

```
 const ids = ["aaa","bbb","ccc"];
 const factors = [82,40,10];
 document.getElementById("answer").value = ids.reduce((count,id,index) => {
   const { value } = document.getElementById(id);
   return count + (parseFloat(value) || 0) * factors[index];
 }, 0);
```

Comment: You have taken a liking to the OR operator, [haven't you?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43985444/1647737)

Comment: @le_m i think we can say that it is awesome ;)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative you can do is use a [default parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters) for your function.

Your calculate would look something like this:

```
Calculate(aaa=0, bbb, ccc) {
```

And [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21397743/passing-html-input-value-as-a-javascript-function-parameter) covers how to pass html elements as parameters for functions.

Comment: no! Calculate(undefined); or Calculate(document.getElementById("test")) it at least needs a bit more to become an answer

Comment: @Jonasw what do you mean?

Comment: @Jonasw it does, just need to adjust the html to pass in the values from aaa, bbb, ccc.

Comment: if you provide a working snippet (DRY!) i give an upvote ;) ( hint: its a bit more complicated)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using an if/else construct you can rely on the falsy value of an empty string.

Therefore you can initialize all your variables like this:

```
var aaa = document.getElementById('aaa').value || '0';
```

More information on falsy values can be found on the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Glossary/Falsy).